# I'm repeating 36 lines of code seven times (one for each day of the week). Is there a more efficient way?

Tags: php

I have a form with a checklist where users check the days they are available, and then for the selected days there are dropdowns where they choose the hour, minute and AM/PM that they start to be available and finish being available.

The form is in English but once it's submitted the results are displayed in Chinese. Whereas English divides the day into AM and PM, Chinese divides it four ways: early morning (midnight-4.59AM), morning (5AM-11.59AM), afternoon (midday-5.59PM) and evening (6PM-11.59PM).

I've written some code which seems to produce my desired result. I've posted the code for Monday below as an example. For the whole week I have this code repeated seven times with 'monday' changed to the relevant day. That means 252 lines of code for the whole week.

I'm a total beginner at PHP and I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to get the same result?

```
if (empty($fields[monday]['value'])) {
    echo "";}
else {
    echo "- " . $fields[monday]['value'] . "：";}
    if (!empty($fields[monday]['value']) && $fields[monday_start_ampm]['value'] === 'AM' && $fields[monday_start_hour]['value'] === '12') {
        echo '凌晨';}
    if (!empty($fields[monday]['value']) && $fields[monday_start_ampm]['value'] === 'AM' && $fields[monday_start_hour]['value'] <= '4') {
        echo '凌晨';}
    if (!empty($fields[monday]['value']) && $fields[monday_start_ampm]['value'] === 'AM' && $fields[monday_start_hour]['value'] >= '5' && $fields[monday_start_hour]['value'] <= '11' ) {
        echo '上午';}
    if (!empty($fields[monday]['value']) && $fields[monday_start_ampm]['value'] === 'PM' && $fields[monday_start_hour]['value'] === '12') {
        echo '下午';}
    if (!empty($fields[monday]['value']) && $fields[monday_start_ampm]['value'] === 'PM' && $fields[monday_start_hour]['value'] <= '5') {
        echo '下午';}
    if (!empty($fields[monday]['value']) && $fields[monday_start_ampm]['value'] === 'PM' && $fields[monday_start_hour]['value'] >= '6' && $fields[monday_start_hour]['value'] <= '11' ) {
        echo '晚上';}
    if (!empty($fields[monday]['value'])) {
        echo $fields[monday_start_hour]['value'] . '.' . $fields[monday_start_minute]['value'] . ' – ';}
    if (!empty($fields[monday]['value']) && $fields[monday_start_ampm]['value'] === 'AM' && $fields[monday_start_hour]['value'] === '12') {
        echo '凌晨';}
    if (!empty($fields[monday]['value']) && $fields[monday_end_ampm]['value'] === 'AM' && $fields[monday_end_hour]['value'] <= '4') {
        echo '凌晨';}
    if (!empty($fields[monday]['value']) && $fields[monday_end_ampm]['value'] === 'AM' && $fields[monday_end_hour]['value'] >= '5' && $fields[monday_end_hour]['value'] <= '11' ) {
        echo '上午';}
    if (!empty($fields[monday]['value']) && $fields[monday_end_ampm]['value'] === 'PM' && $fields[monday_end_hour]['value'] === '12') {
        echo '下午';}
    if (!empty($fields[monday]['value']) && $fields[monday_end_ampm]['value'] === 'PM' && $fields[monday_end_hour]['value'] <= '5') {
        echo '下午';}
    if (!empty($fields[monday]['value']) && $fields[monday_end_ampm]['value'] === 'PM' && $fields[monday_end_hour]['value'] >= '6' && $fields[monday_end_hour]['value'] <= '11' ) {
        echo '晚上';}
    if (!empty($fields[monday]['value'])) {
        echo $fields[monday_end_hour]['value'] . '.' . $fields[monday_end_minute]['value'] . '<br>';}
}
```

As an example, if someone selects that they're available 4.30AM–2.00PM the result appears in Chinese as:
凌晨4.30 – 下午2.00

Comment: To clarify, the focus on my question isn't anything to do with the bilingual aspect. It's a question from someone new to coding about whether there is a more efficient way to do things than repeat the same/similar code over and over again.

Comment: look into functions

Comment: Either I'm overlooking something or your example code for Monday already is duplicated. The lower part is exactly like the upper part. Can you maybe try to explain what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: @Fitzi It's start and end time.

Comment: Do the chinese symbols depend on the day? If there is no dependency at all, then you should store this in a separate variable. You could also write a function which takes a period (am/pm) and a value and translate this to chinese (for the two of them, you could use constants). This function should not know whether it's start or end hour, you handle this outside of it.

Comment: @DirkScholten I see, totally overlooked that one. Thank you

Comment: `$weekdays = ['monday', 'tuesday', …]; foreach($weekdays as $weekday) { … }` – and then you simply insert `$weekday` in all the places where it currently has the static text `monday`. (So f.e. `$fields[monday_start_ampm]` – which was wrong to begin with, unless you defined an actual _constant_ named `monday_start_ampm` anywhere – becomes `$fields[$weekday.'_start_ampm']`, etc.)

Comment: Thank you to everyone who answered and gave comments. The answers were incredibly helpful, not just because they got the result I was looking for but because they pointed me in the right direction for things to read up on ("switch", "foreach", etc). I obviously have no ability to be able to judge which answer gave better code so if one did and someone wants to point that out in a comment then I'll choose that as the best answer. If not, I'll select @Fitzi 's answer since this had more explanatory comments which was really helpful for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid duplicating your logic for each day, you can use a loop to repeat the same steps on different data.

Additionally, I noticed that you are checking the same thing over and over again (`!empty($fields[monday]['value'])`, etc). You usually want to avoid this too.

An easier solution that works for all your days and avoids the duplicated checks could look something like this:

(I tried to add explanations why I did things this way in the comments, if anything is unclear please don't hesitate to ask)

```
// keep an array of all your field names,
// so we can iterate over all days
$fieldNames = [
    'monday',
    'tuesday',
    'wednesday',
    'thursday',
    'friday',
    'saturday',
    'sunday'
];

// loop over all fieldNames (aka days)
foreach( $fieldNames as $fieldName ){

    // if the value for our current field is empty,
    // skip the loop and continue with the next field
    if( empty($fields[$fieldName]['value']) ){
        continue;
    }

    // save the AM/PM value into a variable, so we don't have to write the long array access all the time.
    // since your field name for the periods is "<day>_start_ampm", we can simply put it together by using the field name
    $startPeriod = $fields[ $fieldName . '_start_ampm' ]['value'];
    $endPeriod = $fields[ $fieldName . '_end_ampm' ]['value'];

    // save the start and end hours to variables too, same reason as above
    $startHour = $fields[ $fieldName . '_start_hour' ]['value'];
    $endHour = $fields[ $fieldName . '_end_hour' ]['value'];

    // instead of always checking time and period, we can convert the time a DateTime object and later work with a 24 hour format
    $startTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i A', $startHour . ':00 ' . $startPeriod);
    $endTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i A', $endHour . ':00 ' . $endPeriod);

    // now we can determine the chinese period
    // since this is something we can reuse on multiple places
    // we put this logic into a function (see below)
    $chineseStartPeriod = getChinesePeriodName($startTime);
    $chineseEndPeriod = getChinesePeriodName($endTime);

    // Finally, we can print our output
    // See https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.date.php for the details of the format
    echo $chineseStartPeriod . ' ' . $startTime->format('G.i');
    echo ' - ';
    echo $chineseEndPeriod . ' ' . $endTime->format('G.i');

}

// this function takes a DateTime object as parameter,
// and returns the chinese period symbol
function getChinesePeriodName( DateTime $time ){

    // here we get our hours back from the DateTime object,
    // but in a 24 hours format. Since format returns a string,
    // we also want to parse our value to an integer.
    $hour = intval($time->format("G"));

    if( $hour < 5 ){
        return '凌晨';
    }

    if( $hour < 12 ){
        return '上午';
    }

    if( $hour < 18 ){
        return '下午';
    }

    return '晚上';
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the help and explanatory comments!